# Why Is The New Auth Dialog Preview Missing Aggregations?

Tags: facebook, dialog, new-operator, authentication

I have enabled the new Auth Dialog and created aggregations. However, when I click on preview auth dialog. It does not look like what it is supposed to.

[image: Auth Dialog]

Comment: In order to get more responses, I suggest you try to explain how you want/expect it to look.

Comment: It should look like this https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/login_add_to_facebook.png/

Comment: anyone??? this is so frustrating. I followed all the instructions still no aggregation previews.

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregation previews are no longer rendered in the Auth Dialog - I think the docs were subsequently updated to show the currently live version, but old screenshots may still be around showing the previews inside the auth dialog